# python 3 imaplib different between windows/anaconda command prompts

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda, imaplib

I have some python code I use for emails that recently stopped working. Trying to debug it, I discovered that imaplib.IMAP4_SSL exists in python started from an anaconda prompt, but not a regular windows command prompt. How is this possible?

Here's the simplest way I know to show:

1. open anaconda prompt and windows command prompt
2. in both prompts, type 'python' to start python
3. both show the same python version (3.7.1 for me)
4. type the following:

```
import imaplib
imaplib.IMAP4_SSL
```

The anaconda prompt returns a class and works fine, while the windows cmd prompt returns an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'
```

I thought maybe I had multiple versions of python installed, so I uninstalled everything related to python that I could find, then reinstalled anaconda. It didn't help.

Comment: Another post mentioned that ssl needs to be available, so maybe I have an ssl problem instead of an imaplib problem. I can import ssl in the anaconda prompt, but not the windows cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305569/how-to-make-batch-files-run-in-anaconda-prompt) by using a batch file. Now I can get my code to work by double clicking in windows. This is the batch file that works for me (in directory with code):

```
set root=C:\Users\usernamen\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
call PythonFileToRun.py
pause
```

I still don't understand what the activate.bat file does or why ssl doesn't work in the windows cmd prompt though.