# conda init doesn't work in bash on Windows

Tags: anaconda, git-bash

I install Git-Bash and conda on my Windows, which provides two program: `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` and `C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe`.

The latter, `C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe`, does not work with conda properly. When I try to `conda acitvate base`, I get a message:

```
Administrator@##### MINGW64 /bin
$ conda --version
conda 4.7.12

Administrator@##### MINGW64 /bin
$ conda activate base

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I tried `conda init` and `conda init bash`, then close and re-open the `bash.exe`, but it just remains the same.

Any idea on how to fix the problem?

## Possible work around:

I am concerned with this issue because VSCode's Integrated Terminal uses it. I tried to use `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` as Integrated Terminal, but it opens a new window, instead of 'Integrated' in VSCode.

The `git-base.exe` works fine with conda, so guides on how to setup `git-base.exe` as VSCode Integrated Terminal is also acceptable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda and Git Bash in Windows - conda: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501167/anaconda-and-git-bash-in-windows-conda-command-not-found)

Comment: Thanks @Simba . But I actually have `conda` in my path. I call `conda --version` and the bash displays conda's information successfully.

Comment: I had the same problem. I renamed my ```.bash_profile``` to ```.bashrc``` and it worked

Comment: @Auss this worked for me, can you explain why?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile helped me.

Comment: @Auss Unless you know what these files already contain, it is better to copy .bash_profile to .bashrc instead of renaming it. These are files sourced in different occasions and it might cause an issue in the future with interactive login or similar

Answer (score 8):

For me there were two problems:

1. `conda init` creates a `.bash_profile` file with the correct initialisation, but `git-bash.exe` loads `.bashrc` (thanks to [Auss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388190/conda-init-doesnt-work-in-bash-on-windows#comment107520003_58388190)' comment)
2. My bash home directory was not equal to my windows home directory. Conda created `C:\Users\<username>\.bash_profile` and bash needs `~/.bashrc`, but `~/` was not equal to `C:\Users\<username>\`.

My solution was to

- run `code ~/.bashrc` from the git terminal in VS Code to make sure the `.bashrc` is created in the right location
- copy the contents of `C:\Users\<username>\.bash_profile` and paste into the opened `.bashrc`
- Reopen the Git terminal

Comment: I did as explained in this solution, but that was not enough for me.

I had to do the following as well:

1. Open git bash AS ADMIN
2. $ conda init bash

- This seemed to modify this file: C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh

After that I can use the following command successfully in VS Code (in new bash terminal):
$ conda activate <Name-of-Virtual-Environment>

Answer (score 5):

Append the configuration in .bash_profile to the .bashrc file

```
conda init bash
cat ~/.bash_profile >> ~/.bashrc
```

`conda activate $ENVNAME` should work after a bash restart.

Comment: In my case, I had 2 instances of Git Bash with 2 different home directories. Copying both files to both "home" directories made both instances work correctly with conda

Answer (score 1):

In my case simply typing `conda init bash` in `git bash shell` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to .bash_profile solved it:

```
. /c/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

(See answer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501167/anaconda-and-git-bash-in-windows-conda-command-not-found) for more information)

Answer (score 0):

Only usefull for a handfull of people:

`conda init` requires `bash` behind it. So use `conda init bash` or any other shell name. Stupid mistake but simple fix.