# Anaconda: conda activate <env> vs activate <env>

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, conda, git-bash

In my Windows Command Prompt, if I run `activate <env-name>` it activates the environment without any issue. However, in other terminals for example Git Bash, the `activate <env-name>` does not work. I have to explicitly prepend `conda` infront of the command, like, `conda activate <env-name>`.

I need Git Bash to work with `activate <env-name>` because I did setup Git Bash as the default terminal in my VS Code and whenever I initiate a terminal from inside VS Code, it opens up Git Bash session and tries to execute `activate <env-name>`, eventually failing to activate my intended environment automatically.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about the Windows folder configuration (Windows users please chime in), but the `activate` script is installed in the **base** environment's `bin/` and/or the `Scripts/` directory. Generally, it is recommended to transition to `conda activate` since Conda v4.4. However, this is slightly complicated on Windows + Git Bash, for which the standard `conda init bash` does not directly work, but there are [directions in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58388190/570918) on getting it working.

Alternatively, one could set up an alias to in the `.bashrc` file that Git Bash loads,

```
echo 'alias activate=/path/to/conda/bin/activate' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Just be aware that this is a non-standard practice, and Conda may not continue to deliver the `activate` script.