conda invalid choice: activate on MobaXterm
I am trying to use Anaconda3 through MobaXterm on Windows 10. I've followed the usual instructions for installing both.
I initially had some issues using conda from the local terminals in MobaXterm at all. Adding the Anaconda3 locations (/path_to_conda/Anaconda3 and /path_to_conda/Anaconda3/Scripts) to $PATH seemed to fix this, and I was able create a new conda environment myenv.
Unfortunately, when I try to conda activate myenv I get:
conda-script.py: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate'

I checked whether this conda activate myenv works in the Anaconda Prompt: it does. There seems to be an issue with conda not being init'ed for MobaXterm, but running conda init in the local MobaXterm terminal does not solve the issue.
I've tried to see whether source activate myenv works, but this gives:
/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
: numeric argument required

I've also tried solutions such as the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170202/7855276, but this results in:
bash: $'\r': command not found
bash: /path_to_conda/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'ash: /path_to_conda/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: line 10: `)

I am guessing this is a syntax issue between bash and the Windows terminal? I'm don't know how to resole this. Maybe adding the bash equivalent of this to MobaXterm's .bashrc works. I'm hesitant to try that, since conda init changes lots of files in the background and I don't know if just adding a few lines to .bashrc suffices.
