# Is there a way to run batch files with Anaconda prompt

Tags: batch-file, anaconda

I have a notebook that I am trying to automatically execute using a batch file, but to do so I need it to launch in the Anaconda prompt. Based on the suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305569/how-to-make-batch-files-run-in-anaconda-prompt), I was able to get the batch file to open it by calling the activate.bat, but it wouldn't run the second part.

```
@echo on
call %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\mccom\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\mccom\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3 
papermill file.ipynb file_out.ipynb
```

Any tips?

Comment: You're not running `papermill file.ipynb file_out.ipynb` in the same instance of cmd.exe as your `activate.bat` is being run. The environment and variables defined within `activate.bat` are therefore undefined once that instance closes, and before that command is invoked. Additionally, the `/K` option is to run the command following it but keep the instance of cmd.exe open until you close it. Your batch file doesn't therefore run `papermill file.ipynb file_out.ipynb` until the `activate.bat` environment is disposed of upon closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Advice of Compo, calling papermill before calling anaconda worked.

```
@echo on
call C:\Users\mccom\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
call papermill New_Send_Email_Personal.ipynb New_Send_Email_Personal_out.ipynb
pause
```